# Tmux: how to use current date&time in save-buffer filename?

Tags: linux, tmux

how can we append current date&time when saving pane history with save-buffer?
What I need/tried:

```
> capture-pane -S - -E - ; save-buffer "$HOME/logs/tmux/tmux-saved.#{pane_start_command}-#(date +'%b.%d.%Y-%H:%M:%S').log";delete-buffer'
```

-> does not work,date part returns empty..

I can use the same #(date) format for example to set pane-border-setting :

```
> set -g pane-border-format "#{pane_index} #(date)"  /works fine
```

One solution(?) would be I guess to store date&time in tmux local variable first and use it with save-buffer later, but I could not figure it out how to store shell command output in tmux variable..